# Cognito adminDeleteUser user pool does not exist error

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

Why does the AWS Cognito adminDeleteUser function as shown in the code below give a "User pool does not exist" error message?

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.accessKeyId = 'aaaaaaa';
aws.config.secretAccessKey = 'sssssss';
aws.config.region = 'us-west-2';
const CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new 
aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

// this section of code produces a correct userPool object
let poolData =
{
    UserPoolId: 'ppppppp',
    ClientId: 'ccccccc'
};
let userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
console.log('userPool: ', userPool);

// this section of code reports error: "ResourceNotFoundException: 
User pool ppppppp does not exist."
let params =
{
    UserPoolId: 'ppppppp',
    Username: 'nnnnnnn'
};
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminDeleteUser(params, (err,data) =>
{
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log('user deleted');
});
```

Comment: The same error is reported when using the adminGetUser function.  What is required to properly utilize the CognitoIdentityServiceProvider "admin" functions?  Can someone provide an example of working code that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been resolved by changing code from

```
aws.config.accessKeyId = 'aaaaaaa';
aws.config.secretAccessKey = 'sssssss';
aws.config.region = 'us-west-2';
```

to the following

```
aws.config.update(
{
    accessKeyId: 'aaaaaaa',
    secretAccessKey: 'sssssss',
    region: 'us-west-2'
});
```

Note also that the following code creates a userPool object whether or not a valid UserPoolId value is provided:

```
let poolData =
{
    UserPoolId: 'ppppppp,
    ClientId: 'ccccccc'
};
let userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
```